# NullPointerException in collision detect

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, collision-detection, collision

I make game using libgdx and box2d. I have dynamic body and static. When dynamic body collides with static the dynamic should back to the start point (vector(0, 0)). 
My Contact method:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    body = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    bodyBanana = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
    body.getUserData();
     if(body.equals(bodyBanana) )
        {
            body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0 , 0));
        }
}
```

and I call this in my render() method:

```
this.beginContact(contact);
```

but I have got NullPointerException in line:

```
if(body.equals(bodyBanana)
```

I have no any ideas what is going on? Thanks for help.

Comment: I do not understand why to you call beginContact on your own. This should be only called by box2D when a contact happens aka contact listener. If I missed something let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yep,you shouldnt call contact in your own. Good to notice I also got NPE the last time I used boxd2, in the contacts, and the code was exactly the one I used before. Probably an update brought that behavior. For me it was as easy as ignore that particular contact

```
bodyBanana = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
if(body==null || bodybanana==null) return; //add this
body.getUserData();
```

Note. I wasnt the only one that now gets invalid contacts, as you.